# How to solve installing issue in CommunityToolkit.Maui.MediaElement

Tags: xamarin, maui

When I'm tring to install CommunityToolkit.Maui.MediaElement below error occured.How to solve the issue

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   NU1202  Package CommunityToolkit.Maui.MediaElement 1.0.1 is not compatible with net6.0-ios16.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0). Package CommunityToolkit.Maui.MediaElement 1.0.1 supports:

- net7.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v7.0)
- net7.0-android33.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v7.0)
- net7.0-ios16.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v7.0)
- net7.0-maccatalyst16.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v7.0)
- net7.0-tizen7.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v7.0)
- net7.0-windows10.0.19041 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v7.0) MediaElement    C:\Users\world\source\repos\MediaElement\MediaElement\MediaElement.csproj   1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like your project is targeting .NET 6 and the .NET MAUI Community Toolkit MediaElement supports .NET 7 and up.

Open the csproj file of your .NET MAUI project, find the `TargetFrameworks` node(s) and update each `net6.0` to `net7.0`. You'll find a couple depending on which platforms you're targeting like: `net6.0-ios` change that to `net7.0-ios`.

After that, reload the project, wait for the packages to be restored en try to install the MediaElement again.

Comment: Thank you.Could we use "CommunityToolkit.Maui.MediaElement" Nuget in a project that was created in .net 6?

Comment: @dotnetdeveloper22 The only way for you to use the MediaElement is to upgrade the .NET 6.0 project to .NET 7.0, which can be done by simply editing the *.csproj* file and changing all references of the `TargetFrameworks` from 6.0 to 7.0.

Comment: @dotnetdeveloper22 as a general rule something that supports a version, let's say 7, can never be installed onto something that is using a lower version, let's say 6. In version 7 maybe things have been added that are needed for a certain functionality to work. Maybe APIs were added that don't even exist in version 6. If the plugin is using 7 and the main app is using 6, the plugin would try to use functionality that doesn't exist and crash. The other way around typically works depending on backwards compatibility. If your main app is version 7 and the plugin is version 6, that should work.